# Gitlab defaults to localhost

Tags: gitlab

I've successfully installed Gitlab on a cloud server but every time I try to create a new project it defaults to localhost so if I try to push to it it attempts to push to the the local machine instead of the remote one.

Is there any way to set an IP address for the destination push?

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

There's a part in your `config/gitlab.yml` that says something along the line of `replace "localhost" with...`. And the restart your app.

If that didn't help, post your config.